# Unable to access web site in local IIS 7 server

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis

I recently made a sample web site with MVC3. Now I want to host my site on my local IIS Server but I can't access the site. When I want to access my site, it displays the file directory not the web page.

```
Note : on another machine it works fine.
```

Can anyone help me?